# rails looking into public folder for all URLs in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

My rails app isn't working all of a sudden in production mode as every URL is looking into public folder rather than invoking controller actions, resulting  errors like

```
2016/11/16 11:48:23 [error] 25138#0: *9 open() "/var/www/html/looted/public/admin/products" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 125.99.106.246, server: www.looted.com, request: "GET /admin/products HTTP/1.1", host: "www.looted.com"
```

When I run it in development, everything works fine. Am running passenger on nginx server with below configuration

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  looted.com www.looted.com;
    root /var/www/html/looted/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    client_max_body_size 250M;
    passenger_app_env production;
}
```

I am using Rails 4.2.4, ruby 2.2.1p85, passenger-5.0.29
Can anybody point me the direction to check what's wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the `config.ru` file is present and Passenger is properly engaged? Are you sure this is the `server` directive being used and some other one isn't overriding it somehow?

Comment: Yes, config.ru is present and below are it's content.    # This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

`require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
run Rails.application`

Comment: You're going to have to do more diagnostics. Broken `routes.rb`? Any errors anywhere?

Comment: I did that, no error in development environment. If `routes.rb` was broken, error would appear in dev also. Everything was working 3 days ago in production, don't know what changed.

Comment: That's what revision control systems are for. Keep digging and I'm sure you'll get it.

Comment: I checked it all and found no discrepancy. Will that be any kind of configuration issue?

Comment: Did all kind of code level diagnostics, no change found that might cause this  problem. Server still running on development and I am running out of time. Can anybody please suggest how to tackle ?

Comment: If you're really pinned you might need to hire an on-demand consultant to fix it like [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com) or [Codementor](http://codementor.io).